# how did i break :method -> :delete

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rest

i refactored my entire application and gave it a whole new design. The one thing that seems to be broken is all the original `link_to` methods I had which were :method => :delete are now getting sent as a GET request.

The only thing I did that I can remember that might cause it is delete jquery-rails from the gemfile (I'm just getting it from google ajax).

Does anyone have any other ideas what I could have deleted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you are right, the `:method => :delete` needs jquery to work.

you have to add the jquery_ujs file to your application layout, and that comes with jquery-rails. You can also install it separately.

https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs

Comment: I'm using jquery in the footer with this   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: then I suggest you open the web developer tools ( firebug, or ctrl + shift + i under chrome/safari) to see what the exact error message is .

Comment: there is no error, at all. it just sets it as GET. and all my other javascripts wrok fine

Comment: no, just jquery 1.7.2 from google. but i just checked my old one and that didnt have jquery-rails on there either